# Converter uma variável para STRING na query mysql no PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Na query abaixo dentro do meu PHP a variável $line[0] não está validando como string, porém se eu dar um var_dump($line[0]); antes de chegar nesta query, mostra que é uma string!

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT player, ip from gru WHERE ip =".$line[0]);
```

Tem alguma forma de converter esta variável para string? Já tentei converter antes da query usando o método convencional, mas não funciona!

Comment: Aparece algum erro? vai ver o indice nem existe.

Answer (score 3):

A pergunta é confusa. Todavia, apenas observando o código, deve ser somente a falta dos delimitadores:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT player, ip from gru WHERE ip = '".$line[0]."'");
```

Comment: Cara, realmente era SOMENTE ISSO! haha estava quebrando a cabeça, sou iniciante nisso! Muito obrigado!!